# delete local branch called "remote"

Tags: git, git-branch, git-remote

I've done something incredibily stupid. I figured I should ask before I tried to "fix" it and accidentally make things worse.

I tried to list all remote branches in my git repo:

```
git branch remote
```

Obviously this isn't the correct command. Instead of listing remote branches, I created a local branch *called* remote. I should have done:

```
git branch -r
```

Can I just remove this branch with:

```
git branch -d remote
```

Will this have any effect on my remote branches? I don't want to accidentally delete anything on the remote side.

Comment: No, that command will only delete the local branch with that name, so you're safe. Happy gitting :-)

Comment: That should be safe, as @cbuckley says. Additionally, if you really want to be paranoid about it, `git update-ref -d refs/heads/remote` is a bit more explicit (as remote branches reside under `refs/remotes/<remotename>/<branchname>`, while local branches are under `refs/heads/<branchname>`).

Comment: Not incredibly stupid. Just a normal mistake. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,

```
git branch -d remote
```

Take a look:

```
MYHOST:git wwheeler$ cd seiso/
MYHOST:seiso wwheeler$ git branch
* master
  trunk
MYHOST:seiso wwheeler$ git branch remote
MYHOST:seiso wwheeler$ git branch
* master
  remote
  trunk
MYHOST:seiso wwheeler$ git branch -d remote
Deleted branch remote (was 15dc59f).
MYHOST:seiso wwheeler$ git branch
* master
  trunk
MYHOST:seiso wwheeler$
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made that mistake too.  One easy thing to do is `rm .git/refs/heads/remote`.

Much of the git repository structure is straightforward, and you can learn a lot by poking around in it.

Comment: Reading @twalberg 's comment above kept me from asking "well is .git/refs/heads/remote the remote repo or my branch called remote"? Thanks for the answer.